# Processamento dos insertes no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

É possível saber se os insertes no MySQL está sendo feitos após fechar a conexão?

O código PHP tem 800 linhas, eu sei que ele vai até o fim, pois a última instrução é realizada com sucesso.

Para acompanha abro o phpMyAdmin e acada F5 vejo que a tabela `cliente` esta sendo populada.

O total de `insert` que é enviado é de 500 mil registros.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack overflow. Da maneira que está sua pergunta ela fornece poucos detalhes e não demonstra esforços de pesquisa. Comece fazendo um [tour] e leia o guia [ask]

Comment: até procurei mais não encontrei nada.

Comment: Os insertes que são enviados para mysql via php ficam executando....  quando eu abro o phpmyadmin vejo que o banco continuar inserindo dados as vezes fica 5 minutos inserindo...

Comment: certo mas é o procedimento .... voce mandou uma carga e ele fica executando, mas acho que para ter uma resposta melhor seria necessário melhorar a pergunta

Answer (score 5):

Para listar o processo de um banco basta acessar o mesmo e fazer a query abaixo.

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Será exibida a lista dos processos ativos.

Comment: Usando este comando em duas hospedagem diferentes percebi que existe tem um problema.... na primeira não informa estas colunas(Rows_sent , Rows_examined , Rows_read)..... imagino que seja esta colunas que indica os processamentos de SELECT ou INSERT ou DELET ou UPDATE.